# How do I get a PHP form page to close on succesful submit?

Tags: php, forms

Is there a quick and easy way to make this form.php code close the window after submitting instead of redirecting? I can deal with the redirect if there is no way to do this, but would like to have the window just close, as the original form is being opened in a new window. Code below:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {

// Used for later to determine result
$success = $error = false;

// Object syntax looks better and is easier to use than arrays to me
$post = new stdClass;

// Usually there would be much more validation and filtering, but this
// will work for now.
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
    $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));

// Check for blank fields
if (empty($post->First) OR empty($post->Last) OR empty($post->Email))
    $error = true;

else {

    // Get this directory, to include other files from
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);


    // Get the contents of the HTML email into a variable for later
    ob_start();
    require_once($dir.'/html.php');
    $html_message = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    // Load the SwiftMailer files
    require_once($dir.'/swift/swift_required.php');

    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport()); // Create new instance     of SwiftMailer

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                   ->setSubject('Hospitality Recycling Program Calculator Results') // Message subject
                  ->setTo(array('bsmith@cleantheworld.org', $post->Email =>$post-> First ))  // Array of people to send 

                   ->setFrom(array('bsmith@cleantheworld.org' => 'Clean the World')) // From:
                   ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html');






    // Send the email, and show user message
    if ($mailer->send($message))
        $success = true;
    else
        $error = true;

}

}
header("location: http://www.cleantheworld.org/newpartner.asp"); 
?>
```

Comment: You could use javascript, but that is not an ideal solution.

Comment: PHP cannot close a window on a browser. You'll need javascript for that. And remember that javascript cannot close a window which was not opened with JS to begin with.

Comment: You would have to use javascript, but a nicer solution would be to not open a new window for your form but just a modal box and use ajax to submit the form.

Comment: I kind of suspected as much, thanks for confirming. I'll just redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @jeroen that a better solution would be to use AJAX but you can just output some javascript in the head of the redirect to close the page. Again I don't recommend this as a good solution to the problem but it will work as long as javascript is enabled in the users browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    self.close();
</script>
```