# Php - using same inputs for different POST

Tags: php

I have a php page that I used to get cli results and display in my browser. I added in a second 'submit' to execute a different variation of the same command, but wanted to use the same input values for both. Ideally I would need 2 submit buttons but just one input. It is just the "select" box I am having problem with.

```
<form action=""method="post">
Username:<br><input type="text" name="user" size="20" tabindex="1">
Password:<br><input type="password" name="password" size="20" tabindex="2">
<!--     -->
<select name="ValueName" size="32" tabindex="3">
<option value="MyValue1">ValueExample1</option>
<option value="MyValue2">ValueExample2</option>
<!--     -->
<button type="submit" style="text-align: left; width:170px; height:25px;         
float:left; " name="test">Test1</button>
<button type="submit" style="text-align: left; width:170px; height:25px;     
float:left; " name="test2">Test2</button>
<!-- Php Section    -->
<?php
$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$ValueName = $_POST['ValueName'];
$test = $_POST['Test'];
$test2 = $_POST['Test2'];

if (isset($_POST['test']))
$cmd = "/usr/bin/curl -k --user $user:$password https://IPADDRESS/DIR1/$ValueName";
if (isset($_POST['test2']))
$cmd = "/usr/bin/curl -k --user $user:$password https://IPADDRESS/DIR2/$ValueName";

while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

My problem is this. In this example page the submit function for "test" works, while "test2" does not. It is essentially the same command, just minor difference. To get this to work I had to add into the html a 2nd select box;

```
<select name="ValueName2" size="32" tabindex="3">
<option value="MyValue1">ValueExample1</option>
<option value="MyValue2">ValueExample2</option>
```

then in php section add;

```
$ValueName2 = $_POST['ValueName2'];
```

and changed;

```
if (isset($_POST['test2']))
$cmd = "/usr/bin/curl -k --user $user:$password https://IPADDRESS/DIR2/$ValueName2";
```

What I would like to do is just use one single  box. Right now on the page I have 2 select boxes, and 2 submit buttons. The "username" and "password" boxes
do work for both submits. I am fine with having 2 different submit buttons, it is having to use 2 different "select" boxes which I can not seem to overcome (especially since they are the exact same)

Comment: Your `select` is not being closed... you probably wants to look at that

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I did as you suggested and found adding a short little javascript to close. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else ever new to Php coming across this same issue, here is the solution. As Samuel suggested, the `select` was not being closed, so I searched and found this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15526451/5645436

```
<script type="text/javascript>
self.close();
</script>
```

Inserting right after the 2 different submit buttons, and the page works perfectly now.

Comment: There you go bud... small things like that make a huge different. Congrats

Answer (score 0):

I see your answer above, however, I suggest you just close your `select`... Using Javascript is not the best solution.

```
<form>
  <select name="ValueName" size="32" tabindex="3">
    <option value="MyValue1">ValueExample1</option>
    <option value="MyValue2">ValueExample2</option>
  </select> <!--CLOSE YOUR SELECT-->

  <button type="submit" style="text-align: left; width:170px; height:25px; float:left; " name="test">Test1</button>
  <button type="submit" style="text-align: left; width:170px; height:25px; float:left; " name="test2">Test2</button>
</form>
```

That should fix any errors you may come across; and that's best practice for HTML, close your tags with their correct tags.

Comment: Is kind of funny now, but when you said close the select, I was looking at the php section. As I know next to nothing with php, I thought I had to add some function. I never saw that I did not add the </select> in the html portion. Even more ironic is when I went back to the page hours later to make it more presentable, I must have inadvertently re-added the close. Because as it is now, the page works and the javascript is gone. Thank you Samuel for helping on this